# npx create-next-app will only ceate a package.json file and then fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, frameworks

I have been trying to create a new nextjs app for a project but I keep getting this error.

I have tried several techniques to create a new nextjs app but the same error continues.

I don't know if it's from my PC configuration or something because; recently, even npx create-react-app started giving the same error on my PC

Here's the error

```
Creating a new Next.js app in C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\websites\nextjs-starter.

Using yarn.

Installing dependencies:
- react
- react-dom
- next

Usage Error: The nearest package directory (C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\websites\nextjs-starter) doesn't seem to be part of the project declared in C:\Users\<user>.

- If C:\Users\<user> isn't intended to be a project, remove any yarn.lock and/or package.json file there.
- If C:\Users\<user> is intended to be a project, it might be that you forgot to list Desktop/websites/nextjs-starter in its workspace configuration.
- Finally, if C:\Users\<user> is fine and you intend Desktop/websites/nextjs-starter to be treated as a completely separate project (not even a workspace), create an empty yarn.lock file in it.

$ yarn add [--json] [-E,--exact] [-T,--tilde] [-C,--caret] [-D,--dev] [-P,--peer] [-O,--optional] [--prefer-dev] [-i,--interactive] [--cached] [--mode #0] ...

Aborting installation.
  yarn add --exact --cwd C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\websites\nextjs-starter react react-dom next has failed.
```

Comment: is there any yarn.lock or package.json in the folder you specified , if so delete and try again

Comment: `C:\Users\<user>` seems to have either a yarn.lock file and/or a package.json file. Consider removing them?

Comment: Do you have space in your username ?

Comment: My laptops user’s name is made up of the name and model of my laptop, so yeah, there’s space in between the words

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks, worked 100%

There was package.json and yarn.jason in there